# Can I implemenet part of interface?

Tags: typescript

can I implement part of interface ?

```
export interface AuthorizeUser {
  RQBody: {
    login: string;
    password: string;
  };
  RSBody: {
    authorizationResult: AuthorizationResult;
  };
};
```

```
class AuthorizeUserRQBody implements AuthorizeUser['RQBody'] {
  @IsString()
  login: string;

  @IsString()
  password: string;
}
```

it gives me `A class can only implement an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't implement something that isn't an interface itself.

You need to pull out that and make it an interface or type.

```
interface RQBody {
  login: string;
  password: string;
}

interface RSBody {
  authorizationResult: AuthorizationResult;
}

interface AuthorizeUser {
  RQBody: RQBody;
  RSBody: RSBody;
};

class AuthorizeUserRQBody implements RQBody {
  @IsString()
  login: string;

  @IsString()
  password: string;
}
```

You might also want to change the name of `RQBody` and `RSBody` so that you don't have fields and interfaces with the same name.

If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> after the name `AuthorizeUser` or inside `[""]`, it doesn't come up with anything useful, which is one way you can tell that you can't do exactly what you wanted to do.

If you really want `AuthorizeUser['RQBody']`, you might be able to do that with namespaces.